# Printing entire line till END of LINE using grep

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I am having the following piece of text.

```
TRACE(FOO, CAT,
    INFO, "Hello World")
```

If I use `grep -r "FOO" file.txt`, grep only prints the first line. I need the whole line to be matched. I only have FOO as the search key. I want to do this with grep.

I tried `grep --after-context=1`, but in cases where my test is `TRACE(FOO, CAT, INFO, "HELLO WORLD"` (i.e no line break after the CAT) it is unnecessarily showing the next line too.

Can you please help me with doing it.

Chid

Comment: What do you mean by whole line? those two are different lines...

Comment: Ok. I need to print till the occurrence of `)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n -e '/FOO.*)/p' -e '/FOO[^)]*$/{p;n;p}' x.txt
```

if sed is also acceptable. and `-n` quiet the output, `p` print the line, `n` goes to the next line.

combine the 2 lines,

```
 sed -n -e '/FOO.*)/p' -e '/FOO[^)]*$/{N;s/\n//p;n;p}' x.txt
```

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to concatenate them and print it as a same line

Comment: @CHID Sure. Just replace {p;n;p} with {N;s/\n */ /;p}